# Simple “hello world” example with opencpu package in R

Tags: r, opencpu

I built a simple R package which contains only one function `helloWorld()` which prints “hello world”.  I need help on deploy this using the R package **opencpu**.  Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [example apps](https://www.opencpu.org/apps.html), in particular the [appdemo](https://rwebapps.ocpu.io/appdemo/www/) package has this [hello world](https://rwebapps.ocpu.io/appdemo/www/hello.html) app.

To deploy this, install `opencpu-server` according to the manual, and then install the appdemo package.

Comment: Got the solution